# Moving Facebook Like Box

Tags: css, facebook

I'm having trouble moving the Facebook like Box next to the rest of the social media icons on:
cardfun.com.au/beautybyjen

Any ideas?

**style.css:**

```
#igbutton { margin-right: 400px;}
```

**header.php:**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=570267666425210& version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="nav">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Fablashextensions"><img     
src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47731225/facebook.gif"/>
    </a><a id="igbutton" href="http://instagram.com/jenlaybeauty"><img     
src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47731225/instgram.png"/></a>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Fablashextensions" data-width="300" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false"     data-share="false"></div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Im a bit confused `#igbutton` is not the facebook icon, its what I think is instagram. Also the rest of the icons are likely not in `header.php` where is this icon suppose to go?

Comment: THe igbutton is for instragram and used to move it closer to the menu links hence #igbutton { margin-right: 400px;}

They are suppose to go where they are now just want to move the FB Like box closer to the other social icons